# Moving red leaf corkscrew hazel

Tags: trees

I've moved house and inherited a red leaf corkscrew hazel, its about 2 metres high. I'd like to move it to a new location. How easy/hard would that be, without harming it?

EDIT:  here's a couple of photos.

[image: tree]

[image: tree2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dig a trench or at least make a cut a foot deep around a circumference of 3', a radius of 1 1/5' from the base of the trunk.  Best to get started now.  Your little tree/shrub needs to get prepared to survive with a manageable sized root ball.  You are going to sever roots leaving this plant using just the roots within a 3' root ball (please send a picture, 3' is manageable 5' is not...for moving DIY but the caliper of the trunk will tell me that might be too small and perhaps a 3 1/2 diameter would be better)?

Take a shovel, flat head is best and punch it down into the soil along the circle cutting the extra long roots from the 'root ball' you are making. Water that plant very very well.  Now would be a good time to use a little fish emulsion or horsetail 'tea' of silica.  Studies have shown these two old fashioned substances provide more 'hardiness'. Just a small amount is beneficial do not over do.  Fish emulsion is mostly N and too much N produces too much growth and just before winter going into dormancy could cause weirded out growth to freeze and die.  Have you fertilized this plant?  Is it close to the lawn?

You could make a trench 12" deep and 6" wide now or before the ground freezes. Water the root ball well.  Fill the trench with straw, not grass clippings or hay.  Or fill with wood pellets (for wood pellet stoves), that will absorb moisture and break down and insulate the live roots from the winter cold.

After cutting the roots the severed roots are growing new feeder roots within new tiny amount of soil. By allowing your plant 6 to 8 months to adjust to the huge stress of root loss, it will fare better with the stress of moving.

Early in the spring, before leaves start growing, you will dig below the root ball to separate it from its old home.  Using a tarp or a 'ball cart' tilt the root ball, then slide the side of the tarp beneath that ball, Then tip the tree the other way onto the tarp, sliding a scooching the tarp fully under the root ball.  3 guys make this easier. Disturb the root ball soil as little as possible.

Make sure there is no old burlap or twine encircling the trunk or branches.  Do not dig the new hole any deeper than the depth of the root ball you were able to remove.  Forget about amending the soil.  Do not add anything to the soil as you transplant this little tree. No compost, no peat moss, no rock, no gravel.  The only thing important is the depth of your hole, unwinding encircling roots with as little disturbance to the root ball as possible.  Back fill with original soil and firm!  Water as you back fill.  If on a slope you have to make a tree well.

If this plant was grown in soil that is different than the soil where you want to transplant a few things to consider.  If the root ball is sandy, transplanting into clay is similar to planting into a concrete swimming pool.  Very bad drainage.  Do not over do the watering!

If this hazelnut has a root ball of clay and is transplanted into sandy soil, when watered, the water is not able to be absorbed into the clay because it is rapidly being drained out and away from the root ball.

Send a picture please.  The longer your plant has between cutting the roots and then being moved the better your chances for success!  Do not do this during the growing season if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you have time and a good back you can do this. You need to find out what kind of soil the plant is growing in.  Sandy soil is a lot easier to dig plants out of than clay soil.
Prepare the plant for the move:

- dig a trench around the plant at least to the width of the branches. Try for a trench a foot deep, the kind of soil will become apparent.
- water the plant thoroughly
- in the spring dig your trench deeper.  How many roots are you encountering? Lots of roots could indicate that rock is close to the surface or that this is a surface rooter
- wait a week or two and finish digging out the plant
- you want to keep the root ball intact. Consider sliding it onto burlap.
- get some strong friends to help you drag, slide the plant to the new location. Hopefully this does not involve a ride in a pickup truck or you will have to wrap the foliage too
- plant the root ball at the same level in the soil as it was previously using the local soil. Do not add bone meal or other enhancements.  It is simply not required for most plants and soil chemistry.

Answer (score 3):

If you are unable to move the grown plant, consider propagating it. Hazel grows quickly and with a bit of patience you’ll soon have a big bush again.

There are three ways to proceed, you can either root them in water (sources vary a bit on how well this works) or directly in soil. I recommend making multiple cuttings just to be sure. The third option is ground layering.

Corkscrew hazel is typically not propagated by cuttings in a professional context (it’s grafted on rootstock instead), because cuttings can be a bit fussy - sometimes they grow like crazy and sometimes not - but if your existing plant is simply too large to move it, it could be worth a try (or two).